# Getting cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I'm getting cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint in Yii framework

I have tried the below which I could see in some of the answers but still not working

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('set foreign_key_checks=0')->execute();
$this->db->createCommand()->checkIntegrity(false)->execute();
$this->getFixtureManager()->checkIntegrity(false);
```

**I get the error as below**

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`yiibasic`.`educations`, CONSTRAINT `FK_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `yiibasic`.`users` (`id`))
The SQL being executed was: TRUNCATE TABLE `users`

Error Info: Array
( 
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1701
    [2] => Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint 
(`yiibasic`.`educations`, CONSTRAINT `FK_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `yiibasic`.`users` (`id`))
)

Can any one help me to correct it. Also can you give the best way of seeding data in Yii I coudn't get a good tutorial for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first disable the constraints : `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`

then truncate your tables

Then reactivate the constraints : `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`